# Read pixel on game (OpenGL or DirectX) screen

Tags: opengl, colors, directx, screen

I want to read the color of a pixel at a given position in a game (so OpenGL or DirectX), by a third-party application (this is not my game).

I tried to to it in C#, the code works great for reading the color of the desktop, of windows, etc, but when I launch the game, I only get #000000, a black pixel. I think that this is because I don't read at the correct "location", or something like that.

Does someone know how to do this? I mentioned C# but C/C++ would be fine too.

Comment: How are you reading the colors now/what methods are you using? Because I encountered a similar issue when using Windows' Magnifying Glass accessibility tool where the desktop and other windows would be shown properly, but anything that bypassed the Windows API and drew to the screen directly (i.e. most games) would show as blank/black. Or rather, anything that drew directly to an overlay, if that's the right terminology.

Comment: Oh, here we go; I don't have a solution, but I'm pretty sure I found your problem. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardware_overlay "As a consequence of hardware overlay use, a screenshot program (for example, the one automatically built into Windows that activates when a user presses the PrtSc key) often does not capture the content appearing in the hardware overlay window. Rather, a blank region containing only the special mask color is captured." So you might have to look into DirectX and OpenGL to see what methods they have available for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In basic steps: Grab the texture of the rendered screen with appropriate OpenGL or Directx command if the game is fullscreen. 
For example with `glReadPixels` you can get the pixel value at window relative pixel coordinates from current bound framebuffer.
If you are not full screen, you must combine the window position with the window relative pixel coordinates.

Some loose example:

```
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, yourScreenFramebuffer);
glReadPixels(/* your pixel X, your pixel Y, GLsizei width, 1 pixel wide, 1 pixel tall, GL_RGBA or GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, *where to store your pixel value */);
```

Answer (score 0):

On Windows there is i.e. GDI (Graphics Device Interface): With GDI you can get the Device Context easily using `HDC dc = GetDC(NULL);` and then read pixel values with `COLORREF color = GetPixel(dc, x, y);`. But take care: you have to release the Device Context afterwards (when all GetPixel operations of your program are finished) with `ReleaseDC(NULL, dc);` - otherwise you would leak memory.
See also [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/dd144909%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for further details.

However, for tasks like this I suggest you to use: [Auto-it](http://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/).
It's easy, simple to use & pretty much straightforward (after all it's just designed for operations like that).

```
Local $color = PixelGetColor(200, 300)
MsgBox(0, "The color is ", $color )
```